# Name Error | Unitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Description:
I have a **file with code in Ruby with Class `Simulator`**, which **include some other files with many other classes**.
Now, I am trying to **use class `Simulator` in my Rails app**. More precisely, in controller. These classes are correct.

I am trying to create `Simulator` object and call method for that in my controller.

Every time, I get an error

> "Unitialized constant" for Simulator, or for classes that it uses.

I tried many things, like:

1. `config.autoload_paths +=`
2. `require_dependence "simulator.rb"`
3. `config.cache_classes = false`

But it still does not work.

**Format of simulator.rb**

```
require 'other_classes...'
class Simulator
   "Using other_classes"
   "Some specific methods"
end
```

Comment: did you reset your server ?

Comment: and where is `Simulator` file placed ?

Comment: Yes, and can you include the contents of that file?

Comment: It's okey with Simulator class and path to this file (it is in root app's folder with other files, which it uses). 
I launched this code with ruby in console (ruby simulator.rb) and it works fine.
About Rails problem:
Full error message is: "Undefines symbol in GameController::Simulator".
I think, there are problems in namespaces.
Now i am reading about ActiveSupprot::Dependencies.

Comment: place it in lib not root and then add lib to autoload_paths or require the file where needed eg. `require Rails.root.join("lib","your_file_name").to_s`

Comment: Now, it's work, but very strange.
As define, Simulator uses 2 files as input. And Controller presets these 2 files. And after that Controller calls Simulator.

Now:
When files are updated(it's ok), Simulator working, like he had old versions of these files. (it's not ok).

I found very funny solution(but this is not what I'm looking for): "system('ruby D:\AI\[AI]Processing\cmd.rb')"

Comment: I need to reload input files every times, when Simulator start working (with Controller Actions). How to do this?